# Bluemix Java Liberty Server App Enable Application Debug grayed out

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud-tools

I have a simple Java EE Bluemix Hello World App that I have imported into Eclipse (Neon) from Github.  I am running this on Mac OS.  I can deploy and run the application on a Bluemix Server from Eclipse.  I have the latest Eclipse Tools for Bluemix Plugin installed (along with the Cloud Foundry Tools Plugin).   If I check my Eclipse Java version via Eclipse Installation Details/config it shows:

eclipse.vm=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib

I would like to debug the application, however, from the server if I right click on the app, the "Enable Application Debug" option is grayed out.  Is there some setting or env variable that I need to set?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I checked the app on Eclipse today and now the option to enable application debug is now available.  I still think the Link with Projects information though is very valuable information, though so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How was the application deployed to Bluemix?  Was it deployed via Eclipse using that particular workspace or it was deployed via CLI or deployed from another Eclipse workspace.

The Bluemix Tools only allow you to Enable Application Debug if the application is deploy directly from the same workspace.  If your application happens to be deployed from other workspace or using other methods like CLI, you have to right click on the application and select *Link with Projects* to establish the link before you can debug the application.